# Ubuntu 18.04 upgrade ton Ubuntu 20 issues

Tags: upgrade, updates

This is the distribution I am currently using:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

So I try to upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04:

```
$sudo do-release-upgrade -d
Reading cache

Checking package manager

Can not upgrade 

Your python3 install is corrupted. Please fix the '/usr/bin/python3' 
symlink. 
=== Command terminated with exit status 1 (Wed Apr  7 17:07:46 2021) ===
```

Then I check my upgrade alternatives:

```
$update-alternatives --display python3
python3 - manual mode
  link best version is /usr/bin/python3.8
  link currently points to /usr/bin/python3.6
  link python3 is /usr/bin/python3
/usr/bin/python3.6 - priority 1
/usr/bin/python3.8 - priority 2
```

So I switch to python3.8

```
$sudo update-alternatives --config python3

There are 2 choices for the alternative python3 (providing /usr/bin/python3).

  Selection    Path                Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/bin/python3.8   2         auto mode
* 1            /usr/bin/python3.6   1         manual mode
  2            /usr/bin/python3.8   2         manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 2
```

And attempt to upgrade again:

```
$ sudo do-release-upgrade -d
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/do-release-upgrade", line 11, in <module>
    from UpdateManager.Core.MetaRelease import MetaReleaseCore
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UpdateManager/Core/MetaRelease.py", line 25, in <module>
    import apt
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'
```

All answers to `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'` didn't help.

What is the way out?

Comment: I'd recommend you to take a backup of your `$HOME/` (assuming all your personal data is in there) and the settings of any manually installed and **customized** software, then use an install media to install 20.04 LTS in fresh partitions. Anything else has a potential to cause problems after the update. Tip: `apt-mark showmanual | less` will show you a list of packages which appear manually installed to `apt`, the list will probably *include* your 'special' software selections.

Comment: quite long list.

Comment: Yes, ponder on which ones **you** *actively* chose to install. Save the list to after the reinstall of Ubuntu (20.04) and compare to the list shown then.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove all third parties ppa's and their packages before upgrade.

Use ppa-purge for that. When upgrade is complete, just reinstall everything you need and may add those ppa's again.

As to python, as soon as ppa's removed, reinstall default one with: sudo apt-get install --reinstall python3

It should fix your issues.

Comment: Execuse me,  do you mean excuting ``ppa-purge . Error bash: ppa-purge: command not found `

Comment: And it should have said to run this command to install it? `sudo apt-get install ppa-purge`  But backup list of ppa, so you can maybe install those in new install. Not all ppa or proprietary drivers all always available or even always needed in a new install.

Answer (score 0):

Make life simple;

1. save your data, i.e. the content of `$HOME/` *(note hidden files! these have names that start with a dot in `ls -lA` output)*, which software packages you have installed, and any customizations you've made to them and others.
2. Check if you should / could / have to re-arrange partitions that are in use by the current installation; take the opportunity to clean up.
3. Arrange to install the new OS version, and do it.

Anything else than the above has a potential to cause problems after the update.

---

Tip:
`$ apt-mark showmanual | less`
will show you a list of packages which appear manually installed to apt, the list will probably include your 'special' software selections.

e.g.
`$ apt-mark showmanual > file_before.txt`
... will save the list for the current OS, waiting for you to save it somewhere.

Use the similar
`$ apt-mark showmanual > file_after.txt`
... after the reinstall, then use

`$ diff -u0 file_before.txt file_after.txt | less`
to check for differences.

In a similar manner you can check any settings file for previously installed software, that you have reinstalled in the new OS.

Note that just copying back a settings file can be problematic, if you have a NEWER version of the same software.

*NOTE, my personal experience is: This **IS** more work, but has proven to be the most "safe" way to avoid trouble, when upgrading.*